# Making a micro MacBook Air (headless)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, hacking

Here's a project I've been desiring for a while. Hopefully this is not too off topic.

I'd like to take a MacBook Air, remove the case, screen, battery, speakers, keyboard, basically everything. I want to have just a motherboard and hsf running osx and usable via vnc over wifi for ultraportable number crunching power.

What problems do you think I might run into? Is there any reason the air won't boot if the aforementioned components are removed?

Comment: Would using a Mini (or at least ripping a Mini apart) be an option as well?

Comment: No because frankly a mini or even just the mobo is too big. I'm really trying to mimic the new android-based "computer on a stick" devices

Comment: What kind of *number crunching* are you planning to do?

Comment: Removing the keyboard will likely be an issue as most computers don't boot without them. I'm not sure how a Mac would behave. You could disconnect the cable and give it a try. Since the Air uses a blade SSD and the RAM is soldered on, it should just be a case of pulling out the MB. Cooling could also be a kink as I'm pretty sure the fans are secured to the case.

Comment: Macs will definitely boot without a keyboard, but you may get a dialog box at the login screen (to help you pair a bluetooth keyboard).

Comment: @jmk so how do you get past that if you don't have one? If he wants to make a headless server running VNC, he won't be able to login without the keyboard then.

Comment: You won't need to log in to use VNC if you're running a recent version of OS X. If you enable VNC in the remote desktop settings, VNC clients are presented with a separate login screen from the one on the live monitor.

Answer (score 1):

[Bart Reardon](http://macbookairproject.blogspot.de/p/so-whats-this-blog-all-about.html) is trying to convert a broken MBA into a "computer in a keyboard". The project looks a bit stuck right now, but from [one photo](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4123/4861851842_97077906e3.jpg) you can see he has removed (some? all?) components from the Mobo. Perhaps you could ask him if the thing still works if everything is removed. I’d be interested to know!